# How do I add Source Control to an existing project

Tags: macos, xcode5

How do I add Source Control to an existing project?

On some of my projects (originally created in Xcode3) I added Source control in Xcode4. I recollect there was an option to do this.

I now want to do similar for some old projects, but can find no way to do so.
I have searched and the only "solutions" I can find is to create a new project, and copy the original source files.
Unfortunately the way Xcode5 structures a new project is quite different, so this is not straightforward.

Is there a way to do this in Xcode5? I could probably do this in git, or even go back to Lion, but I am sure I am not the only person who wants to resurrect an old project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode doesn't have an option to create repositories for existing projects. You'll have to create a git repository from the command line. Launch the Terminal application, navigate to your project's directory, and run the git init command to create a git repository for your project.

If Xcode doesn't automatically recognize the repository you just created, open Xcode's Accounts preferences and add your repository from there.